# Como atualizar o conteudo do meu aplicativo criado no intel xdk depois que ele já esta nas lojas?

Tags: android, html5, intel-xdk

Estou criando um app de noticias no intel xdk, e gostaria de saber depois que publicar ele na loja como faço para atualizar o conteudo, pois está atualização tera que ser diaria.

Comment: como você desenhou sua aplicação? está trabalhando com webService? você poderia criar uma rotina para alimentar sua aplicação sempre que tiver alguma "noticia" nova.

Answer (score 1):

Danilo, a forma de atualizar o conteúdo dependerá de como você contruiu sua app.

A maneira mais comum, como comentado pelo Wellington é utilizar um webservice para obter as notícias e atualizar dinamicamente o conteúdo, dá uma olhadinha neste video https://youtu.be/KtFvvrHNt20?list=PLZL68elhOXv9B9N_O8ghaYXC6HyJJU_Xj que tem um passo a passo de como fazer isso criando uma app no XDK que processa um RSS para exibir notícias de um portal.

Se você não tiver uma fonte online que te forneça as notícias fica mais complicado, pois você terá que atualizar o conteúdo diretamente dentro da app e republicar o apk, isso não é prático pra você a a experiência para o usuário é péssima.